# mysql runing well these days, but it can not start suddenly today

Tags: mysql

I have a server running wordpress on it.
It is running well these days, but today I found it can not connect database.
So I checked server, found mysql service was shutdown.
Then I restart , but it only work for a while, after some seconds, it shutdown again.

This is mysql log:

```
160508 10:07:36 [Warning] IP address '222.186.59.174' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160508 14:08:14 [Warning] IP address '210.209.127.33' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160508 23:08:15 [Warning] IP address '183.63.89.196' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160509 16:08:02 [Warning] IP address '198.55.114.190' has been resolved to the host name '198.55.114.190.static.quadranet.com', which resembles IPv4-address itself.
160510  8:30:34 [Warning] IP address '222.186.134.25' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160510 12:39:02 [Warning] IP address '118.193.255.253' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160510 16:06:36 [Warning] IP address '118.193.218.65' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160511  0:02:03 [Warning] IP address '116.255.183.230' could not be resolved: Name or service not known
160511 00:39:09 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
160511 00:39:09 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160511  0:39:10 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-MariaDB) starting as process 24298 ...
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137756672 bytes) failed; errno 12
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160511  0:39:42 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160511  0:39:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160511  0:39:42 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160511  0:39:42 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
160511  0:39:42 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
160511  0:39:42 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
160511 00:39:44 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
160511 17:11:08 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
160511 17:11:08 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-MariaDB) starting as process 24894 ...
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160511 17:11:08 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: The log sequence number in ibdata files does not match
InnoDB: the log sequence number in the ib_logfiles!
160511 17:11:08  InnoDB: Database was not shut down normally!
InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
InnoDB: Restoring possible half-written data pages from the doublewrite
InnoDB: buffer...
160511 17:11:08  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
160511 17:11:09 Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.5.46-MariaDB-37.6 started; log sequence number 8239814
160511 17:11:09 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160511 17:11:09 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
160511 17:11:09 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
160511 17:11:09 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.47-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
160511 17:12:21 mysqld_safe Number of processes running now: 0
160511 17:12:21 mysqld_safe mysqld restarted
160511 17:12:21 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld (mysqld 5.5.47-MariaDB) starting as process 25104 ...
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.7
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
InnoDB: mmap(137756672 bytes) failed; errno 12
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
160511 17:12:21 InnoDB: Fatal error: cannot allocate memory for the buffer pool
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
160511 17:12:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] Aborting

160511 17:12:21 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete

160511 17:12:21 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
```

I always see there are a lot failed login attempt when I ssh to my server, and you can see there are many ip in log, is attackers caused this problem or my server has been attacked? ?
If not, what happend to my server?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/25165/intermittent-mysql-crashes-with-error-fatal-error-cannot-allocate-memory-for-t

Comment: try this link http://serverfault.com/questions/564748/mysql-mariadb-crashes-frequently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check your memory allocation on server.
Real cause of this problem in error log lines below:

```
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 128917504 bytes)
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 96681984 bytes)
160511 17:12:21 [ERROR] mysqld: Out of memory (Needed 72499200 bytes)
```

Comment: You mean the memory is not enough?

Comment: Yes, I'm 100 % sure it is

Comment: Thanks, I started a service running in background for a few days, maybe it cause this. I reboot my server, and it running well now~